# What do “parergonal” and "parergon" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What do “parergonal” and "parergon" mean in the following sentence? Can anybody suggest some synonym?

> Thus, the figurative signification of structure does not escape but
>   instead confirms the *parergonal* and supplemental status of ornament.
>   If structure in its metaphorical sense is the fully conceived
>   structured idea of the building, then ornament becomes the *parergon*
>   that reifies the underlying essential idea, the recessive unseen
>   structure. (*Source: "Structure/ornament and the Modern Figuration of Architecture" by Anne-Marie Sankovitch*)

I checked them out in American Heritage Online English dictionary and Wikipedia, but I wasn't able to figure it out, and I'm struggling because I'm actually not able to understand what Anne-Marie Sankovitch said.

Comment: Did you try "define: parergon" using Google, a method that was suggested to you in the answer to a different question of yours? Also, Wikipedia is not a dictionary, so if you are looking for definitions, it is not a good source.  You might try Wiktionary instead.  Also, since you are reading academic articles, you should probably consult a more sophisticated dictionary.

Comment: Also, "parergon" is defined earlier in that very article.

Answer (score 1):

From the OED's entry for ***parergon***:

> **parergon** `/pəˈrɝːgɒn/`.
>
> Pl. **parerga** (in 7 *erron*. **parergas**).
>
> Etymology: L. *parergon* an extra ornament in art, a. Gr. *πάρεργον* by-work, subordinate or secondary business, etc., sb. use of neuter of *πάρεργος* beside or in addition to the main work, f. *παρά* beside + *ἕργον* work.
>
> 1. In Painting: Something subordinate or accessory to the main subject; hence, generally and fig., ornamental accessory or addition, grace, embellishment. ? *Obs.*
> 2. By-work, subordinate or secondary work or business; work apart from one’s main business or ordinary employment. Also a work, composition, etc., that is secondary to or a derivative of a larger or greater work; an opusculum.
> 3. †  A supplemental work. (As title of a book.)

Note that senses 1 and 3 are both considered obsolete.

I suggest you gain access to an **unabridged** dictionary.  You aren't going to be happy with all the words that these so-called "learners" dictionaries leave out, like oh maybe . . .  ***opusculum***.